# Row Details for Datatable by Bootsfaces

Tags: jsf, datatable, expansion, bootsfaces

Is there a way to expand Rows in Datatable by Bootsfaces? I'm sure I already saw this example in the show-cases, but I can't find it now anymore:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the `responsive="true"` attribute to your `b:dataTable`:

> If there's not enough screen estate to display the table, the last couple of columns are hidden

Those hidden columns are "moved" to row details.

See:

- https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/DataTable.jsf (scroll to "Responsiveness")

Comment: Okay! I see. Apparently there is no way to activate this option on demande and independently from responsivity.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't implement this feature yet (apart from the special case of `responsive="true"`). However, you can use the JavaScript code shown on the datatables.net page to implement the feature yourself. The only tricky part is how to get the additional data. I guess the best way to achieve this is adding invisible columns to make sure the data is available in the HTML page.

Comment: Sure this does the trick. I'm just looking for a fancier look than this from primefaces table expansion. In this reguard i added yesterday a feature request: github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/787. Thank you for your Replies.